# Formatting CSS output in PHPStorm using Sass

Tags: css, formatting, sass, phpstorm

I'm getting the Sass watchers set up in PHPStorm.  Everything works as it supposed to, but the CSS output is not what I would hope for.  Is it even possible to change the formatting options for output?

For example, I have this as my Sass code:

```
#faq 
  background-color: #ffcc55
  padding-top: 20px
  .faq-button
    width: 30%;
    float: left
```

When transpiled to CSS, I get this:

```css
#faq {
  background-color: #ffcc55;
  padding-top: 20px; }
  #faq .faq-button {
    width: 30%;
    float: left; }
```

While that is perfectly workable, what I would like is this:

```css
#faq {
  background-color: #ffcc55;
  padding-top: 20px; }

#faq .faq-button {
  width: 30%;
  float: left; }
```

Any chance it's possible to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/06/15/different-sass-output-styles/) explains the different ways Sass can be output.

In order to use this in the terminal when you start your Sass watch, it would be:

```
sass --watch sassfile.sass:cssfile.css --style expanded
```